# waiting for device Superoot Galaxy Nexus

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

I decided to super root my galaxy nexus I9250 and i followed this [tutorial](http://droidmodderx.com/galaxynexus/unlock-bootloader-and-root-galaxy-nexus-easily-via-superboot).  I did it up to 7 in which the command promt tells me `<waiting for device>`

How do i proceed?  the device is connected

Comment: Did you perform step 5 correctly?  Reboot your phone and try again.

Comment: yes im on the bootloader, my screen has the android logo with its belly open

Comment: This is often a driver issue. I'd check the Windows device management list and see if you have an unrecognized device or anything of that nature. You can also try `fastboot devices` to make sure it's being recognized (if you don't get a result from that command then it's not being seen by fastboot).

Comment: Yea i think it is a driver issue because I tried looked in Windows device management and i tried to re-install but my computer won't recognize the phone.  it shows (Unknown device), it just installs and fails.  How would i solve?

Comment: You could try the [Galaxy Nexus Root Toolkit](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1454314). It has a driver setup of feature of some sort, and I think it provides instructions for manually setting it up if the automated install fails. I don't know much beyond that, unfortunately.

Comment: Yea it didn't work :( it just says Unknown Device under the device manager and the drivers are up to date.